# asterisk diamond with even number c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work with an even number to make something like this;

Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern: 6

```
  *
 ***
*****
*****
 ***
  *
```

I keep getting it with an extra row.

```
   *
  *** 
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int NUM = 6;


int i=0, j=0; 
//NUM=NUM-1;
for(i=-NUM; i<=NUM-1; i++)
{
    //cout<<i<<"part1";
    for(j=-NUM; j<=NUM-1; j++)
    {
         //cout<<j<<"part2";
         if(abs(i)+abs(j)<=((NUM-1)/2+1))
         {
              cout<<"*";}
         else
         {
              cout<<" ";}
    }
cout<<endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Your output is worse than you suggest. In the outer `for` loop `i` goes from `-6` to `5`. That turns out to be 12 lines. You are not showing the empty lines of output in your post.

Comment: +1. Beginner-level question, but it has code, actual & desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Envision each row as two numbers: `x`) number of space, and `y`) number of stars. So for you example you get:

```
i  x y 
------
0: 2 1
1: 1 3
2: 0 5

2: 0 5
1: 1 3
0: 2 1
```

Observe that the bottom half is just the top half "upside down", which means counting backwards.

Now, create an expression that converts from `i` to `x` and `y`. For example `x=2-i` appears to work (it might be more complicated, but let's try that for now). Do a similar thing with `y`. Now write code using the following psuedo code.

```
for i=0..2
    for x (which is some expression involving i)
        write a space
    for y (which is some expression involving i)
        write a star
    write a newline

for i=2..0
   (repeat above, better yet, write a function to do it call it twice
```

Alternatively, you could use an if statement to computer `x` and `y` when the table looks like:

```
i  x y 
------
0: 2 1
1: 1 3
2: 0 5
3: 0 5
4: 1 3
5: 2 1
```

For example: `x` is `2-i`, when i<3 and `i-3` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since your output is symmetric, it helps to divide the algorithm such that the it works in a symmetric way.

For `N = 6`, you need `6` rows and `5` columns.

You could have the index in the outer loop go up `0, 1, 2`, and then come down `2, 1, 0`.

And you could have the index of the inner loop go `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2`.

Then, given `i` (the index of the outer loop) and `j` (the index of the inner loop), the spot is a white space if:

```
(i+j) < 0 || (i+j) > i*2
```

Now the program can be:

```
int isWhite(int i, int j, int NUM)
{
   return ((i+j) < 0 || (i+j) > i*2);
}

void drawDots(int i, int NUM)
{
   // j = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
   int j = 0;
   for( j = -(NUM-1)/2; j < NUM/2; ++j)
   {
      if( isWhite(i, j, NUM) )
      {
         cout<<" ";
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"*";
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   int NUM = 6;
   int i=0; 

   // i = 0, 1, 2
   for ( i = 0; i < NUM/2; ++i )
   {
      drawDots(i, NUM);
      cout<<endl;
   }

   // i = 2, 1, 0
   for ( i = NUM/2-1; i >= 0; --i )
   {
      drawDots(i, NUM);
      cout<<endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Update**

`drawDots` can be a bit more streamlined if you don't mind replacing the `if/else` block with code that uses data from a local array.

```
void drawDots(int i, int NUM)
{
   char s[] = "* ";
   // j = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
   int j = 0;
   for( j = -(NUM-1)/2; j < NUM/2; ++j)
   {
      cout << s[isWhite(i, j, NUM)];
   }
}
```